# Browsersync with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, browser-sync

I'm using Browsersync in a .NET app.  I have iis set with Windows Authentication only (anonymous authentication is disabled). I'm getting 402.1.  Of course I can set anonymous to enabled and it will load the page but I'll be in anonymous which is not the desired result.  I'm not quite sure what options to set in Browsersync to make this work in Windows Authentication mode.

I'm using the below and thinking it's due to incorrect headers??

```
browserSync.init({
        proxy: {
            target: 'http://localhost:4300',
            reqHeaders: {
                "host": config.urlObj.host,
                "accept-encoding": "identity",
                "agent": false
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Looks like no updates. Anyone find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The `middleware` part will pass the relevant headers from the original request to IIS.

```
browserSync.init({
        proxy: {
            target: 'http://localhost:4300',
            reqHeaders: {
                "accept-encoding": "identity",
                "agent": false
            },
            middleware: function (req, res, next) {
                if (req.headers.x-logon-user) {
                    res.setHeader("X-Logon-User", req.headers.x-logon-user);
                }
                if (req.headers.authorization) {
                    res.setHeader("Authorization", req.headers.authorization);
                }
                next();
            }
        }
});
```